# Apple Map issue with around 2000 annotations

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, dictionary, mkmapview

We've integrate Apple native map in our iOS application. But, we're facing some performance issue when playing with Map.Can we get some better performance if we will replace Apple native map with Google map OR Do we have any other way ??

Comment: What kind of performance issues?

Comment: responsiveness of map is not good.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any map is going to like having 2000 annotations added to it, personally I think you need to sit down and work out a way of greatly reducing that.  Perhaps only show visible annotations then add and remove them as the user scrolls around.  Or if they zoom out 200 groups into 1.

It will be a job but worth it.

Comment: I like your answer a lot and really agree with you. It makes great sense to add and remove annotations as the user scrolls around. There's no point of adding annotations that the user can't see yet. You could just make use of the MapKit delegate methods to detect when/where the user has scrolled to and then just load in the appropriate annotations.